# Chaining commands with && after "start /b" in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to spawn multiple processes to recursively convert `.doc` files within a folder into `.docx` using Microsoft's `wordconv.exe`. I know this will spawn an unlimited number of them, so that is not the issue here.

Here is what I have:

```
@echo off

set "WCONV=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Wordconv.exe"

FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.doc) DO (

        echo "%%F\%%X"

        start /b "" %WCONV% -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && del "%%X"

    )
    popd
)
```

The problem is that `del "%%X"` seems to execute upon successful completion of `start /b` instead of upon completion of `%WCONV% -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx"`, so the original `.doc` file gets deleted before `wordconv` gets to work on it.

How do I group `%WCONV% -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && del "%%X"` so that it works as one command for `start /b` to spawn?

**EDIT to clarify:**
If I run the script sequantially, without `start /b`, it all works fine, as in docs get converted and deleted only if the conversion is successful. This is what I mean:

```
@echo off

set "WCONV=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Wordconv.exe"

FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.doc) DO (

        echo "%%F\%%X"

        %WCONV% -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && del "%%X"

    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: `del` on its own is not a command, it is only a built in instruction within `cmd.exe`.  It sounds to me like you're wanting to either `start` a new `cmd.exe` instance, and within that instance, run `%WCONV%` and `del`, or to just get rid of `start` with its associated options. Oh and BTW, when you use `*.doc` like that, or even with the `dir` command, it will also pick up `.docx` files. This means that your `.docx` files are likely be put back into the running loop and be parsed again.

Comment: Everythign works sequantially if I omit `start /b "" `, so that's not the issue. I'm trying to spawn processes that will each run wordconv and then delete the original file upon successful completion. `docx` does not get picked up.

Comment: I gave you two options, you've decided that you do not want to use the option which omits `start`, so try the other one!

Comment: How do I do that? `start "" cmd %WCONV% -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" ^&^& del "%%X"` just opens command windows in the respective folders and does nothing.

Comment: You should be doublequoting the arguments to `cmd.exe`, i.e. `Start /B "" cmd /C "%WCONV% -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && Del "%%X""`. Note that you should really change your `set` command to `Set "WCONV=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Wordconv.exe"` and then use `Start /B "" "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C ""%WCONV%" -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && Del "%%X""`; I have additionally included the full path to `cmd.exe` in the latters version, it isn't necessary, but I added it to show that the additional doublequotes will not cause any harm.

Comment: Yes, it's the same conclusion we have arrived to in the answer below. Coming from a PHP background, I didn't know you could use double quotes within double quotes :) Also, I was already using `Set "WCONV=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Wordconv.exe"`, but I miss-corrected. Thank you!

Comment: No point in having the nested `FOR` commands. You should be able to do this with a single `FOR /R` command.

Comment: @Hlsg using double quotes within double quotes is no rule. It's a special thing with the `cmd` command. There are about 20 lines in `cmd /?` how double quotes are handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `&&` is indeed not part of the spawned subprocess. To force the parser to include them, escape them:

```
start /b "" "%WCONV%" -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" ^&^& del "%%X"
```

(note: personally, I would use `/min` instead of `/b`, but ymmv)

Based on the comments, the following should work for you:

```
start /b "" cmd /c ""%WCONV%" -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && del "%%X""
```

Comment: Tried that and now the docs get converted, but not deleted afterwards.

Comment: works for me (although with another command, as I don't have `Wordconv.exe` - and with `/min` instead of  `/d`. All those processes you spawn with `/d` share the same window, which I find very confusing - especially, if they don't terminate)

Comment: Same result with `/min` and `/b`. Works, but docs are not deleted afterwards. Mind you,  sequentially, without `start /b ""` and with `&&` everything works, so it's not `wordconv` that's to blame.

Comment: Have you tried to add just `start` without the b switch and add another `^&^& pause` to see if there is a result or error for the non deletion? Also remove `@echo off` while debugging as the code stephan posted must work. Might be that you have a non 0 `errorlevel` keep in mind double `&&` only allows next command if errorlevel is 0. Else try single `^&`

Comment: Tried that too. Same result: processes get spawned, docs get converted, but not deleted afterwards. Curiously, even without the `/b` switch, cmd windows do not open for each.

Comment: Try single `^&` instead and see if delete occurs.

Comment: @Hlsg could you please try `start "" cmd /k "%WCONV% -oice -nme  "%%a" "%%ax"  && del "%%a""` and give the results?

Comment: @Stephan `start "" cmd /k "copy "%%X" "%%Xx" && del "%%X""` works, but if I try to replace `copy` with `%WCONV% -oice -nme` I get `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: That's a minor problem, to be solved with another pair of quotes. See my edit please.

Comment: Thank you! `start /b "" cmd /c ""%WCONV%" -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && del "%%X""` works, but it opens double the number of processes. Can this not be done without `cmd`?

Comment: yes, it *should* work without `cmd`, but you said explicitely earlier, it doesn't.

Comment: Alright, it will have to do, thank you, sir! I'll mark this as answered. Please edit your answer with `/b` and `X` instead of `a` for further reference.

Comment: I'm going to assume, as already mentioned in my comment that the reason for opening double is because of the `.docx` files are being reparsed by the `For` loop. Lets take a directory containing 2 files, `doc1.doc` and `doc2.doc`, you run the conversion against `doc1.doc` which outputs to `doc1.docx` and doc1.doc is deleted, this means that *.doc is now picking up `doc2.doc` and `doc1.docx`, it runs against `doc2.doc` which outputs to `doc2.docx` and deletes `doc2.doc`, your loop will then pick up `doc1.docx` and `doc2.docx`, to parse, these will be run against the converter again!

Comment: @Compo No, curiously, `.docx` does not get picked up. The reason for double the processes is that one is `CMD` and the other `wordconv` for each file, as opposed to just `wordconv` were it to work without `cmd /c`.

Comment: @Hlsg could you retry my first suggestion? I added some quotes.

Comment: @Stephan Tested with the same result: .doc files not getting deleted

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try, I've added an additional `If` statement to be sure that no files are cycled back into the `For` loop.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "WCONV=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Wordconv.exe"
For /D /R %%F In (*) Do (
    PushD "%%F"
    For %%X In (*.doc) Do (
        If /I "%%~xX"==".doc" (
            Echo "%%F\%%X"
            Start /B "" Cmd /C ""%WCONV%" -oice -nme "%%X" "%%Xx" && Del "%%X""
        )
    )
    PopD
)
```

However, using the `Where` command you can isolate only the `.doc` files. Also you probably don't even need to nest a `For` loop within another:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "WCONV=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Wordconv.exe"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Where /R . *.doc 2^>Nul') Do (
    Echo "%%A"
    Start /B "" Cmd /C ""%WCONV%" -oice -nme "%%A" "%%~nxAx" && Del "%%A""
)
```

*In the lower example, depending upon how `Wordconv` works, you may need to replace `%%nxAx` to `%%Ax`.*

Comment: The former works like the above selected solution while the latter places all resulting .docx files in the current directory and doesn't delete the original .doc files. The only way to improve upon the aformentioned solution would be to somehow get this to work without `cmd /c` as per my original question.

Comment: @Hlsg, did you read the note at the foot of my answer, it explains what change to make should my latter example do what you've reported it does!

Comment: If I do that, it works correctly, excepot in the case of files found in folders that contain subfolders. Regardless, it's still the same number of processes as in the selected answer, so I don't see the point. `.docx` files don't get picked up anyway.

Comment: @Hlsg, my answer was simply to show you how to ensure when you want to work on a specific extension, how to do that. The answer provided by myself in the comment area and Stephan above, is the best you're going to get, if you're not willing to do it by simply removing the unnecessary `Start` command.

Comment: If you take a look at the `Where` command I used, @Hlsg, you'd note that it used `/R` for a recursive search. This means that it returns all files within the current directory, **`.`** and all its subdirectories. I'm not sure therefore how it isn't picking those up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Wordconv.exe is buggy. I preferred to use libreoffice, 
but you can replace it with any program in the variable "WCONV=anyprogram.exe"

First, set path on the command line:

```
set path=%path%;c:\your libreoffice location
```

Or

I preferred to include the libreoffice path directly on the windows system, windows+pause > advanced config system > path variables > path > edit > new > include path of libreoffice folder

```
@echo off
set "WCONV=soffice"

FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.doc) DO (

        if not exist "%%X" echo Not exist ".doc" on the folder "%%F"    

        %WCONV% --headless --convert-to docx "%%X" "%%Xx"

        if exist "%%Xx" echo convert and delete "%%F\%%X" && del "%%X"

    )
    popd
)
```